# Building MSI for both 32 Bit and 64Bit in MS Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, 32bit-64bit

All,

I would like to put both files related to 32-Bit and 64-Bit in a single MSI project
Let me know if any body has done it

Thanks
Rajneel

Answer (score 2):

Only 32 bit MSI packages can be installed on both x86 and x64 machines. However, a 32 bit MSI package cannot write in 64-bit locations on a x64 machine, like "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Windows\system32". It will always be redirected to "C:\Program Files (x86)" or "C:\Windows\SysWOW64". Do you need the 64-bit files to be installed in the 64-bit locations?